# to count the tag with same name in an XML using libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

i want to count the tag with same name in the complete xml using libxml2. please suggest if there is any inbuilt function in libxml2 for this which directly returns count.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using XPath. See [XPath examples](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#XPath). Once you obtain the result of [xmlXPathEvalExpression](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathEvalExpression), you simply write:

```
xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeNr
```

Here is [XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) given. For example `//elem`, to count all `elem` elements.

And the full function based on the xpath1.c example:

```
int count(xmlDocPtr doc, const char* path)
{
    int count;
    xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx; 
    xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj; 

      /* Create xpath evaluation context */
    xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if(xpathCtx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to create new XPath context\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    /* Evaluate xpath expression */
    xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(path, xpathCtx);
    if(xpathObj == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to evaluate xpath expression \"%s\"\n", path);
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 
        return(-1);
    }

    count = xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeNr;
    printf("count of %s: %d\n", path, count);

    xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Rather than xpathing for `//tagName` and counting, you could xpath for `count(//tagName)` and check obj->floatval.  I don't know if it will take the optimization step of not keep around the full list of matches while running.